# Is there an idiomatic way to listen for changes to the DOM using the Prototype library?

Tags: javascript, events, dom, prototypejs, listener

I'm trying to add a listener to DOM change events. I was hoping something as simple as 'dom:loaded' was baked into Prototype. I'm not sure of the 'Prototype-way' to handle this.

EDIT: I cannot control every case in which the DOM may be altered, so I can't get away with firing a custom event on every DOM change.

Comment: Could you provide a use case scenario that you are trying to accomplish with this? For example, what do you want to have happen every time the dom is modified? And what will be modifying the dom?

Comment: I can't speak for Mark Hawley, but I was considering such a mechanism for setting up cross-browser two-way binding between DOM attributes and text values on one hand and custom JS object properties on the other hand.

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard handler to watch this. However, you can fire custom events in Prototype. Combined with Function.wrap, you should be able to do exactly what you need.

Essentially, you take any function that can modify the DOM, such as Element.insert(), and wrap it with a function that fires your change event:

```
Element.prototype.insert = Element.prototype.insert.wrap(
function(original) {
    var ret = original.call(this, $A(arguments).slice(1));
    document.fire('dom:changed');
}.bind(this)
);
```

Now, whenever you call Element.insert, it will fire 'dom:changed', which can be watched with Event.observe().

I can't guarantee what I just wrote is 100% perfect nor 100% versatile, but it should get you started.

Comment: I think he means the Prototype javascript library, not the OO technique.

Comment: Hmm..that's unfortunate. I don't have access to everything that could potentially alter the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you take a look at the documentation for [Event.observe](http://prototypejs.org/api/event/observe) from the prototype documentation.

As an example using dom:loaded

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {     
                // Some Javascript Code
                  });
```

And an example of Event.observe

```
$('step_anchor_' + i).observe('click', function(a, b){
        return function(){pm.loadData(a, b, true)};
            }(profile.steps[i].action, profile.steps[i].dao_id)
                   );
```

I should point out that obviously document also has an observe function that is specifically designed to listen for events on the entire document such as dom:loaded.

Comment: I understand this -- I'm interested in what event I need to observe in order to detect that the DOM has changed. I was hoping for some sort of 'dom:changed' event like the DOM level 2 DOMEvent MutationEvent.MODIFICATION.

Answer (score 0):

$(element).observe('click', function(event) { someFunction(event); } );
//someFunction will be called on the click event.  This can be changed to any other event.

http://prototypejs.org/api

Go to Element to see more.

Answer (score 0):

I think here is appropriate answer: [Can javascript listen for "onDomChange" on every Dom elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324647/can-javascript-listen-for-ondomchange-on-every-dom-elements) .
Check out DOMSubtreeModified, DOMNodeInserted etc.