# Can javascript listen for "onDomChange" on every Dom elements?

Tags: javascript, events, dom

My question is somewhat weird, but can i add events for any DOM elements(div), like
'onHtmlChange', to be notified when that div has changed their content?

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't ever require such an event. What exactly would make the HTML of any given element change?

Comment: GMaps is feeding an DIV with his content. But the root of my question is just to mimics a dataflow programming approach :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [DOMNodeInserted](http://javascript.gakaa.com/domnodeinserted-description.aspx) and [DOMNodeRemoved](http://javascript.gakaa.com/domnoderemoved-description.aspx).

Ben Nadel recently blogged the following: [Detecting When DOM Elements Have Been Removed With jQuery](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1623-Ask-Ben-Detecting-When-DOM-Elements-Have-Been-Removed-With-jQuery.htm)

Comment: Seems like the OP wants to know when HTML content inside of the divs has changed though.

Comment: @seth —Browsers which use the W3C model should fire both `DOMNodeInserted` and `DOMNodeRemoved` when changing a node's contents, even it it's just text nodes (just tested FF3).  The IE trick mentioned in the linked article could easily be extended to `.html()` and `.text()` to mimic this.

Answer (score 1):

The DOMNodeInserted and DOMNodeRemoved are part of the [Mutation Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) which is now deprecated. Hence, you need to take a look on [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). I did the same in one of my project which is I needed to listen to the DOM changes of a certain element., e.g. DOM append, remove, attribute, and data changes.

These links will help you :

1. http://gabrieleromanato.name/jquery-detecting-new-elements-with-the-mutationobserver-object/
2. https://github.com/kapetan/jquery-observe
3. [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener/11546242#11546242)