# How to test if a jQuery selectors condition is more than 2 times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fire jQuery event on div change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979738/fire-jquery-event-on-div-change)

I'm using this tiny plugin to watch for changes in the html: https://github.com/jacobrelkin/jquery-watcher

This works fine, the problem is I need the `if condition` to validate if it's over 2 times, reason being when the gallery loads and it shifts left and right creates the `-moz-grabbing` condition twice onload.

I tried doing

```
  if(  $('#gallery-1').has('div').css('cursor', '-moz-grabbing') > 2)
  if(  $('#gallery-1').has('div').css('cursor', '-moz-grabbing').length > 2)
```

I also tried putting it in a variable then doing `> 2`

None of the above seem to be working not sure what I'm doing wrong?

```
$('.sliderContainer').watch('innerHTML', function() {
    if(  $('#gallery-1').has('div').css('cursor', '-moz-grabbing') ) {
        console.log($('#gallery-1').has('div').css('cursor', '-moz-grabbing'));
        $('#collapse_content_1').toggleClass('collapse_inner_off');
    }
});
```

Comment: checking for a vendor prefix may not be the best idea... what if the user is using Chrome?

Comment: I would look at the JavaScript that is causing the HTML to change. Looking at the end result isn't a good idea.

Comment: That plugin is using polling with `setInterval(..., 700);`. Use it with caution or Try a different approach.

Comment: Cant do it using OR operator in your condition?

Comment: @BrunoSousa I'm really looking to validate if the condition is met over 2 times

Answer (score 1):

`.css('cursor', '-moz-grabbing')` actually *sets* the stylesheet rule.  You probably want to use `.filter`:

```
$('#gallery-1').has('div').filter(function () {
   return $(this).css('cursor') == '-moz-grabbing';
}).length > 2
```

Comment: is that the if condition? sorry very new to jQuery

Comment: Yes, you can put that in the `if ()`

Comment: unfortunately the .length > 2 isnt doing what its suppose to do, it still loads with the condition less than 2 times