# .on() change function does not fire when updating text using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, onchange

I'm trying to update text using jquery, and I'm trying to fire some functions with .change() but nothing works.

```
<div class="btn btn-tag" data-toggle='dropdown'>
  Explore
</div>
```

When this text changes using jQuery functions (using .text() in jquery) it does not alert:

```
 $(body).on('change','btn-tag',function() {
   alert('test');
 });
```

When it changes text, its supposed to alert, but it doesn't why is this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure divs don't have a change event.

Comment: where you suppose to be change on body ?

Comment: Did you mean `'.btn-tag'` instead of `'btn-tag'`? And what would be the expected behaviour of the `change` event on a `<div>`?

Answer (score 2):

You can not apply change event to body, div, span etc rather you can apply to input type like text, checkbox etc. You can periodically pool the contents to check the change in the element childs or you can use `DOMNodeInserted` and `DOMNodeRemoved` to check if elements are added or removed, for details check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979738/fire-jquery-event-on-div-change).

```
$(body).on('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved','.btn-tag', function(event) {
         if (event.type == 'DOMNodeInserted') {
        alert('Content added! Current content:' + '\n\n' + this.innerHTML);
    } else {
        alert('Content removed! Current content:' + '\n\n' + this.innerHTML);
    }
});
```

Note that `DOMNodeInserted` and `DOMNodeRemoved` does not work every where and the DOMNodeInserted event is buggy in Internet Explorer 9, it is not fired when a node is inserted for the first time, [reference](http://help.dottoro.com/ljmcxjla.php).

Comment: Compatibility table required. I'm pretty sure DNI and DNR don't work everywhere.

Comment: Actually, OP only _delegates_ to `body`. You have removed the delegation.

Answer (score 2):

Div can't have `change` event you can apply `click` though:

- delegate body in `''`
- class selector prefix with `.`

like this:

```
$('body').on('click','.btn-tag',function() {
   alert('test');
 });
```

But if you are trying to update your div with some `dropdown values`:

try this bin: <kbd>http://jsbin.com/ulecom/1/edit</kbd>

```
$('select').change(function(){
  if($('.btn-tag').text() == $('select').val()){
    alert('test');
  } 
});
```

Comment: **You can not apply change event to body, div, span etc rather you can apply to input type like text, checkbox etc.** -- [**above answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14701466/1723893)