# jquery detect new data in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

In gmail web chat  or any other web chat how can we detect that some new text is entered

In gmail these are the attributes when i do an inspect element

```
  <div chat-dir="f" class="km" role="chatMessage" aria-live="assertive">
  <div class="kk">
  ...
  ...
  </div>
  </div>

  <div chat-dir="t" class="km" role="chatMessage" aria-live="assertive">
  <div class="kk">
  ...
  ...
  </div>
 </div>
```

I have used the following but i do not see the alert().Since the text is appended to some previously html how can we get the chat data for processing

```
$("div.km").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
  alert("tree changed");
});
```

or can we use chat-dir attribute to get the data

`EDIT 1:`

I tried the following for gmail chat and even once i didnt see the alert()

```
$(".AD").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    alert("tree changed");
});
$("div.kk").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    alert("tree changed");
});

$('div.kk').on('webkitAnimationEnd animationend', 'div', function(e){
    console.log(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() + ' added!');
    alert("heree")
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("hello world in ready");  
    $('div.no').on('webkitAnimationEnd animationend', 'div', function(e){
        console.log(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() + ' added!');
        alert("heree")
});
$('div.no').change(function() {
    alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});
$('div.kk').change(function() {
   alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});
$('.kk').change(function() {
  alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});
alert($('.kk').val());
$('km').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function(event) {
if (event.type == 'DOMNodeInserted') {
    alert('Content added! Current content:' + '\n\n' + this.innerHTML);
} else {
    alert('Content removed! Current content:' + '\n\n' + this.innerHTML);
}
});
});
```

Comment: If i remember correctly, mutation events are deprecated, so some sort of polling would probably be the way to go for consistency ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fire jQuery event on div change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979738/fire-jquery-event-on-div-change)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way (albeit it only works on those browsers that support CSS `@keyframes`) is to use a CSS animation to animate (however briefly) the newly-added content, and detect the `animationend` (or, in Webkit, the camel-cased `WebkitAnimationEnd`) event, a simple proof-of-concept, with the following HTML:

```
<button id="add">Add more content</button>
<div id="holder"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#holder').on('webkitAnimationEnd animationend', 'div', function(e){
    console.log(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() + ' added!');
});

$('#add').click(function(){
    var addTo = $('#holder');
    $('<div />', {text: addTo.children().length})
    .appendTo(addTo);
});
```

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes newContentAdded {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes newContentAdded {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes newContentAdded {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

#holder div {
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-animation: newContentAdded;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.1s;
    /* Chrome, Chromium, Webkit (future-opera?) */
    -webkit-animation: newContentAdded;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.1s;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CCV5f/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [`@keyframes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@keyframes).
  - [Using CSS Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_animations).
- jQuery:

  - [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Hi for the example u have given i tried the code as in EDIT1 in the question..I still do not see any alerts..I tried this on chrome..Any more suggestions.Basically i am trying build a chrome extension where the extension can read the chat data