# POST to PHP page on div change

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

The below is my code. Div id jp_current_track_title changes automatically when other events occur. I am trying to capture whats gets into the div "Track_title and post it onchange to like.php. as of now i cant figure it out. Im getting something back into the result div but its not posting. What am i doing wrong?

```
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#track_title').change(function() {
                        var content = $('#track_title').html();
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'like.php',
                            type: 'POST',
                            success: function(info){ $("#result").html(info)
                            },
                            data: {
                                content: content,
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of detecting changes in `jp_current_track_title`, can you capture the other events that caused the update to `jp_current_track_title`? If so, can you get the updated title from there?

Comment: yep that worked. var content = $('.jp_current_track_title').html(); right under  $('.jp_current_track_title').text(obj.title)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to get 'change' events when the contents of a div change, it doesn't work like that.

See here:

[Fire jQuery event on div change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979738/fire-jquery-event-on-div-change)

The main answer mentions how you can track DOMNodeInserted / DOMNodeRemoved / DOMSubtreeModified events, however those don't work in IE.

Your best bet is to use setTimeout() and check the innerHTML of the div on regular intervals to see if the value has changed.