# Javascript Eventlistener for Update / Change on Element / innerText

Tags: javascript, onchange, addeventlistener, event-listener

Is there a eventListener who is just checking the changes of an innerText?

Example:

12345

I just want to check if "12345" is changing to something else like "23415".

There is no "click" event that will comes up or anything else. I don't have the chance to go through the code where the updates from the span's are coming. So I really can just only grab the event from the changes in the span element but I don't have any clue how.

Sorry for my bad English and thanks!

Comment: Is your question a duplicate?  Check here to see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979738/fire-jquery-event-on-div-change

Comment: It wasn't, because iam using pure javascript and not jquery or any other framework. Would be much easier with jquery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Using it you can listen to changes of the observed element's `characterData`. Example:

### HTML

```
<span class="observable" contenteditable="true">12345</span>
```

### JS

```
var observables = document.querySelector('.observable');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation);
  });    
});

var config = {characterData: true, subtree: true};
observer.observe(observables, config);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9P83S/1/)

Note that `subtree` has to be `true` because the text actually is a child element of the observed element.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone is looking for a way to do this for multiple nodes. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/steady/xLowm3k5/) [Further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30807846/can-a-single-mutationobserver-object-observe-multiple-targets)

**HTML**

```
<span class="observable" contenteditable="true">13436</span>
<span class="observable" contenteditable="true">13235</span>
```

**JS**

```
var observables = document.querySelectorAll('.observable');
console.log(observables);
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation);
  });
});

var config = {
  characterData: true,
  subtree: true
};
observables.forEach(function(node) {
  observer.observe(node, config);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer might not work on all browsers if the text being updated via the `innerHTML` property. In this case, Firefox (as of 28) treats this as a `childList` event type, while Chrome (as of 33) treats this as a `characterData` event type. My guess is Chrome checks if the child node being update is a text node.

Firefox will fire `characterData` mutation events if the text is updated via user input (like via `contenteditable` as in the example).

In conclusion, if you want to watch for Javascript updating the `innerHTML` of an element, make sure to add `childList:true` to your [`MutationObserverInit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#MutationObserverInit) object to be compatible with Firefox.