# Is there an event checking if the 'innerText' property of HtmlElement has changed?

Tags: c#, html

I'm running c#'s WebBrowser object on html and getting the innerText property for an HtmlElement. Now I want to check when this innerText is changed. 
Is there some onChanged event that does that?

Comment: do you have a code/fiddle to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this on stackoverflow itself [innerText Changed event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613754/javascript-eventlistener-for-update-change-on-element-innertext) this might help you. if you want to try  [MutationObserver.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) try this also.

Answer (score 2):

A quick google gave me the following answer

```
$('#div').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
   alert('change');
});
```

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L72ozx5L/).

Hope this helps.