# Specify which element triggered MutationObserver on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

With the help of the following [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30807846/can-a-single-mutationobserver-object-observe-multiple-targets). I know it is possible to track multiple elements with a single `MutationObserver`-object. I want to track the text of two elements on a website, so I write the following script:

```
var seconds = document.getElementsByClassName('sr-lmt-0-ms-countdown__time srt-primary-7 srm-large')[2];
var minutes = document.getElementsByClassName('sr-lmt-0-ms-countdown__time srt-primary-7 srm-large')[3];


var callback = function(mutations) {
    for (var mutation of mutations) {
            // do something
            // console.log(mutation + (minutes or seconds));
        }
    };

var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
var config = {characterData: true, subtree: true};

observer.observe(minutes, config);
observer.observe(seconds, config);
```

How can I alter this script so the Console shows which variable triggered the `MutationObserver`?

**Edit**

If I inspect `mutation.target` I see the following:

[image]

I don't see whether `sec` or `minutes` triggered the mutation? How can I make this distinguishing?

Comment: `mutation.target`

Comment: Did you take a look at [the specification of `MutationObserver`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-mutationobserver)? It's all there.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I added the output of `mutation.target`, but its still unclear to me

Comment: @amn, to be fair I did but I am struggling with it

Comment: This: "_How can I alter this script so the Console shows which variable triggered the MutationObserver?_" - where you have comments `//do something`, place `console.log(mutation.target)` - that should explicitly answer your question.

Comment: @RandyCasburn then the output shows only the integer that represents the second or, less frequently, the minute

Comment: I don't think I can help you any more than I have. First off, a `var` doesn't trigger a mutation event - an element in the DOM does. Second, if you see an integer that you know represents seconds, the event _must_ be caused by the DOM element that is referenced by the `seconds` variable and the same for the `minute` - can you make that connection? If you want the DOM element itself, it is in the `.parentElement` property of the `mutation.target`. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Thanks for your time sofar. I understand that an element triggers a mutation event. I defined two `vars`, each represent a different element in the DOM. I want to know which one does. If I inspect the text of both elements, it can be either one; a `1` can represent a second or a minute. If I look at the  `.parentElement` property I see `sr-lmt-0-ms-countdown__time srt-primary-7 srm-large`. There are a total of 4 elements that are located using the above and `document.getElementsByClassName()`. How can we identify mutation events caused by either `minutes` or `seconds`? I don't see how

Comment: Add a custom `data-` attributes to the elements - then `mutation.target.parentElement.dataset` - test for the name.

Comment: thank you very much!!

Answer (score -1):

```html
let observer = new MutationObserver(mutationRecords => {
  console.log(mutationRecords); // console.log(the changes)
});
```