# jQuery on method to monitor change in div

Tags: jquery

I have a div `divCoapp1` whose DOM structure can be changed using javascript or ajax calls

How can i attach an eventhandler to its content change?

I have followed this which uses bind method --> [Fire jQuery event on div change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979738/fire-jquery-event-on-div-change)

Something like this

```
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved','#div1coApp1',function(){
                alert('Hello');
            });
```

But since bind is now deprecated i want to use on method. How can i do that ?

Comment: Your code is using `.on` and it is correct.

Comment: look at mutation observers

Comment: Can you please check the jQuery version.

Answer (score 0):

Check this. I am using bind it is working perfectly for me **NOTE :** change your selector body to document ..
Exmaple: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/XaTCh/394/)

```
 $('body').on('DOMNodeRemoved DOMNodeInserted','#rem', function(e) {
   alert("Changed");
});
$('#delete').click(function(){
$('#rem').remove();
});

$('#insert').click(function() {
   $('#rem').append("<p>kamd</p>");
});
```

Comment: Question say that i do not want to use bind method since it is deprecated.