# JQuery Div content change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, visualforce

I would like to capture the event when the div content change and display some alert before the div content change. Below is what I am doing....

```
jQuery('#myDiv').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
        alert('SUDIPTA ... Hi there, hello');
});
```

But seems like alert message is not coming. Can you please help me? Thanks.

Comment: info for your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979738/fire-jquery-event-on-div-change

Comment: Your code works for me. More background is probably needed in order to understand the complexity here.

Comment: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8046

Answer (score 0):

```
var div_eTypes = [],
div_changes = [];
$(function() {
$('#myDiv').each(function() {
    this['data-initialContents'] = this.innerHTML;
}).bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function(event) {
    div_eTypes.concat(e.type.match(/insert|remove/));
    div_changes.concat(this.innerHTML);
});
```

});