# I did a cycle2 slideshow. I want to trigger JQuery function when specific image in slider is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle2

**HTML**

```
 <div class="cycle-slideshow" id="cycle-1" style="float:left;" 
   data-cycle-fx=scrollHorz 
   data-cycle-timeout=3000 >

 <img src="./responsive/img/java1.gif">
 <img src="./responsive/img/java2.gif">
 <img id="trigger" src="./responsive/img/clown.gif">
 <img src="./responsive/img/java4.gif">
 </div>

<div id="target" style="position:absolute;top:50px;left:350px">
        <img src="./responsive/img/java5.gif">  
</div>
```

The slideshow works.  I want to hide the static image  (id="target") when the clown image is active in the slider and make it visible again when any other image is active in the slider

the jQuery function is something like this when clown image is active:

$('#target').css('visibility','hidden');

I did a JsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mapsylno/nA9Yx/4/

Comment: finally found easy and dirty solution: using hasClass function in an indefinite loop. see JsFiddle update:  http://jsfiddle.net/mapsylno/nA9Yx/5/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

[Fire jQuery event on div change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979738/fire-jquery-event-on-div-change)

You could have a div change event on `cycle-1` , check which image is being displayed in it's handler and toggle the css on the `target` image accordingly.

This won't work on IE as is explained in the answer I've pointed you to.