# JQuery on change not working on div

Tags: jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/qmLpakuq/

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="info-price" id='newrange'></div>
```

and here's my JQuery:

```
$( document).on( "change", ".info-price" ,function() {
    console.log("umerjaved");
});
```

Comment: [onchange is only fired on input, select and textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) elements.

Comment: What if I want to detect changes on a div?

Comment: What changes would those be?

Comment: The innerHTML or you can say value

Comment: In that case [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657686/jquery-event-detect-changes-to-the-html-text-of-a-div) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979738/fire-jquery-event-on-div-change).

Comment: What would be making those changes?

Answer (score 1):

you could use setInterval and clearInterval methods. Set interval would be active only when neccessary, like this:

```
var infoPrice = $('.info-price').html();
var infoPrice_changeFirers = $('.square').add('.infobox').add('#pr-slider');
var my_interval = null;

$(infoPrice_changeFirers).on('mousedown', function(){
    my_interval = check_infoPrice();
});

$(infoPrice_changeFirers).on('mouseup', function() {
    clearInterval(my_interval)
});

function check_infoPrice(){
  my_interval = setInterval(function(){ 
  var current_infoPrice = parseInt($('.info-price').html());
   if(parseInt(infoPrice) != current_infoPrice){
     on_infoPrice_change();
     infoPrice = $('.info-price').html();
   } 
  }, 50);
  return my_interval;
}

function on_infoPrice_change(){ // place your code here
  alert('hello');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the `onchange` event isn't fired for `div` elements. The `DOMSubtreeModified` event is now deprecated, and using a timer seems a little bit hacky.

The correct way to do this is by using a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

```js
var targetNode = document.getElementById('my-div');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if(mutation.type === 'characterData') {
     document.write('targetNode changed:<br />');
     document.write('Was: ' + mutation.oldValue + '<br />');
        document.write('Now: ' + targetNode.innerHTML);
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(targetNode, {
  characterData: true,
  characterDataOldValue: true,
  subtree: true
});

// Make a change one second after the page is loaded to trigger the observer.
setTimeout(function() {
  targetNode.innerHTML = 'New Value';
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="my-div">Initial Value</div>
```

If you need to support IE versions older than 11 then you'll need to use a polyfill: 
https://github.com/megawac/MutationObserver.js
https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs