# converting livequery to live/delegate/?

Tags: jquery, livequery

Searching hasn't revealed a solution to my question so asking here.  I've been using livequery() for a while now in combination with live().  Generally, I use live() for known events like click but using livequery for triggering on a specific selector and applying a plugin.  For example...

```
$('#childDomains').livequery(function() {
  var element = $(this);
  element.jqGrid({
    // plugin initialization here
  });
});
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to do the same thing using live() / delegate() or some other cool jQuery feature I don't know about.  I'm attempting to lighten my dependency load and I noticed that livequery hasn't been updated since 02-2010.

UPDATE: I guess I'm not being clear enough.  I have a page that uses jqGrid and turns a TABLE element into a jqGrid Ajax data grid.  There is no real click event for this to occur.  The page that this table is on is loaded via ajax and anytime the DOM sees $("#childDomains") it should apply the jqGrid plugin to that element.  Just like my livequery example is doing.

From my understanding thus far, I don't believe this is possible without livequery, but I wanted to ask to make sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there are no clearly better ways to do that using jQuery; I would say livequery is the best method at the moment.

That said are other possible ways to do it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220188/how-can-i-determine-if-a-dynamically-created-dom-element-has-been-added-to-the-d/850995#850995) someone has rolled their own polling code to detect when an element is inserted into the DOM. You could adapt this, but as far as I can see livequery is already doing this for you.

Another way is to listen for `DOMNodeInserted` events as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814219/jquery-use-element-with-domnodeinserted) but this is [deprecated in the W3C Level 3 Events Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeInserted), due to [poor performance](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/2009AprJun/0072.html). It is also [not IE compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143929/domnodeinserted-equivalent-in-ie).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893937/preferred-way-of-modifying-elements-that-have-yet-to-be-created-besides-events) has some good discussion on monitoring `DOMNodeInserted` events and an alternative of hooking into any methods that can change the DOM. (It is a little old, but from my research nothing has changed yet).

In conclusion, keep using livequery.

Also note that from jQuery 1.7 .live() ([deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/)), and .delegate() ([superseded](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)) should be replaced with  [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (and .die() with [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)). The new methods do not introduce anything that can resolve your livequery dependency though.