# How to specify a method callback when a Backbone View is inserted into the DOM?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone-events

I need to run a layout script as soon as my views are inserted into the DOM. So...

```
$(".widgets").append(widgets.render().el)
$(".widgets .dashboard").isotope # <-- This needs to be called whenever new widgets are inserted
```

The problem is I have to insert new widgets a few different views and re-call this script a few different places, which is not DRY. I am wondering how I can define the `isotope` in the View class.

Would it be a good idea to define an event listener to watch for append into the ".widgets" and to run the script? Is there a built in way of building views that are smart about when they are added to the DOM?

(For that matter, it would be also useful to define a callback for when a View is removed from the DOM.)

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324647/can-javascript-listen-for-ondomchange-on-every-dom-elements

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. I'm looking for a solution rooted in Backbone, but thanks for that link.

Comment: Well, the solution is that you attach a listener in your view that calls `this.isotope` upon insertion. So like you append(widget.render().el) where it needs to go. Widget's initialize function binds the `isotope` method to the DOM insert event. That's about as rooted in backbone as you can get especially  since backbone doesn't have a native facility for that. I say it's a dupe because what you're looking to do is "do something when the Dom is modified". Regardless of your framework, that's the essence boiled down (unless I missed something)

Answer (score 0):

How about calling the isotope each time the view is `render`ed? You'll need to be careful to call `render()` only after the widget is injected, but this ought to take care of your problem:

```
 //in Backbone.view.extend({
   initialize: function() {
     // fix context for `this`
     _.bindAll(this);
   },
   render: function() {
     // .. do rendering..
     this.isotope();
     return this;
   }
 // }) // end .extend
```

Comment: I tried that. The problem is the HTML won't be in the DOM until it's been appended by the parent view.

Comment: Might need to break the insertion into two steps? `widgets.render(); $(".widgets").append(widgets.el)`

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
var self = this;    
this.$el.on('DOMNodeInserted', function(evt){   
self.isotope();
$(evt.target ).stopPropagation();
})
```