# html/js: is there a "page loaded" event in single page applications?

Tags: javascript, html, singlepage

I'm building a single-page-application which (pre-)loads the content of different pages via ajax. when the user navigates, the app replaces the old content inside a specific tag with the new content (ajax data). this new content could be e.g. an article containing text and images.

my question is: **is there an event that is fired, after replacing the content and every external resource of the new content is loaded?** like a "dom ready" for a refresh of the DOM?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324647/can-javascript-listen-for-ondomchange-on-every-dom-elements

Comment: I don't think so any event is fired there.. But you can use the ajax call backs to do so.

Comment: @enhzflep I know when the node is inserted because I do it myself ;) so the `DOMNodeInserted` event doesn't help. @mtk but the ajax callbacks are fired when the html arrives from the server - I need an event after this content is attached to the DOM and the resources (images etc) are loaded.

Comment: Well, in that case (I was mistaken when I though there was a DOMContentChange event), one would suppose that the way to do it would be the 'normal' way - i.e, count the elements that will require loading and attach an onload or onerror handler to increment the number of loads/fails. In any case, I'd do a test - I guess you'd have fewer elements than could be processed before the first resource loaded. I guess document.querySelectorAll('#conainerId img') would be my first port of call. It's likely you're aware of that and looking for a cleaner solution. :) Interesting question, btw. bookmarked.

Comment: @enhzflep yep, thought of that but a cleaner solution would be great.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Yes, [jQuery has a `document.ready` event](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) that should work for you.</strike>

You can however [replicate jQuery's event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795089/need-help-with-jquery-to-javascript/1795167#1795167), if you don't want to import the library.

**Edit**

Turns out I wasn't paying attention.

No events are being fired when the DOM is modified, so it's not possible to add a listener on anything like that.

You will have to keep track of the modifications on the DOM, manually. You could add "callbacks" to the modification functions you use:

```js
function addSomethingToPage(data){
    data.doSomething():
    domReady();
}

function domReady(){
    //re-usable "callback"
}
```

Comment: jQuery's `document.ready` is only called once at first pageload - so this doesn't work.

Comment: the problem (or question) is still the same: when exactly to call `domReady()` because `data.doSomething()` is async (image loading etc). like enhzflep mentioned [in his comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13472522/html-js-is-there-a-page-loaded-event-in-single-page-applications#comment18433814_13472522), I can add EventListeners to every `<img>` but I was hoping for a cleaner solution ...

Comment: If such a cleaner solution exists, I'm not aware of it, I'm afraid.