# Detecting HTML modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not even sure if this is in the realm of possibility.  Is there a way to detect a change in a webpage's HTML content?  For example, I have a webpage with an image in the center, if someone decides to remove the image element from the page's HTML source, is there a way to detect the removal?  Or do I need to use something that loops and checks the page every second or so (Using JS)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can javascript listen for "onDomChange" on every Dom elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324647/can-javascript-listen-for-ondomchange-on-every-dom-elements)

Comment: Which platforms are you targeting? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: How would someone make such a change? *If you are concerned about changes made using FireBug or Chrome Dev Tools, note that those changes occur only on that specific user's own computer, no where else.*